# Can no longer edit control from Visual Studio Design View

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm working on a control and have been editing it's View from the VS Design View. I have not edited the Designer.cs file, only the .cs file. However, all of a sudden now (Monday) I can no longer see the Control in the Design View. What would cause this to happen? And how can I fix it?

EDIT: this is what I tried. I read that for a User Control `this.DesignMode` will always be false, and so it should be checked in the Load event as I've done here, except I still can't use Design View. Ideas?

```
            this.Load += (sender, args) =>
                         {
                             if (this.DesignMode)
                                 return;

                             try
                             {
                                 DateTime timeWhenLoaded = DateTime.Now;
                                 this.LoadLayouts();
                                 this.LoadScheduleView(timeWhenLoaded);
                             }
                             catch (Exception ex)
                             {
                                 log.Warn("Something went wrong while setting up the Layout Scheduler", ex);
                             }
                             finally
                             {
                                 this.FormIsOpening = false;
                             }
                         };
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors that show up in the `Error List` Visual Studio window?

Comment: You probably added code to the constructor or the initialize or the Load event that throws an exception. Do you check in your code if your form is in DesignMode?

Comment: @rene No I don't, I'll try that!

Comment: @rene What exactly should I do / suppress if I do find that it's being loaded in design view?

Comment: I updated the original post with more information @rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular control has a DataGridView that uses a special extended class to make a CalendarColumn. This is an inner class. For the sake of readability, I had placed this inner class in a region ABOVE the declaration of the class which is being designed. Once I moved it back below the declaration of the class being designed, the designer popped right back in to view!